# How to post information from an html form to a database using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to insert information from a html from using php and add it to database using phpmyadmin. i have a number of select boxes and text boxes, I am using an insert query but cant get it to work.

Here is my code

the from

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Payment</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        </head>

<body>

<form method="POST" action="paymentback.php">
Card Type
<br>
<br>
<select name="card"required>
<option value="visa">Visa</option>
<option value="mastercar">MasterCard</option>
<option value="visadebit">Visa Debit</option>
<option value="maestro">Masestro</option>
</select>

<br>
<br>

Card Number
<br>

<input type="text" name="cardnumber"required>

<br>
<br>

Expiry Date
<br>
<br>
<select name="expiry" required>
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
<option value="05">05</option>
<option value="06">06</option>
<option value="07">07</option>
<option value="08">08</option>
<option value="09">09</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
</select>

<select name="expiry"required>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
<option value="2016">2016</option>
<option value="2017">2017</option>
<option value="2018">2018</option>
<option value="2019">2019</option>
<option value="2020">2020</option>
<option value="2021">2021</option>
<option value="2022">2022</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>

Card Security Code
<br>

<input type="text" name="securitycode" required>



<br>


Cardholder's Name
<br>

<input type="text" name="name"required>

<br>
Address line 1
<br>

<input type="text" name="Address1"required>

<br>
Address line 2
<br>

<input type="text" name="Address2">

<br>

Address line 3
<br>

<input type="text" name="Address3">

<br>

Town/City
<br>

<input type="text" name="town"required>

<br>
<br>
<input type="submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is the backend php code

```html
<?php

if($_POST["submit"])
{
    $card = $_POST['card'];
    $cardnumber = $_POST['cardnumber'];
    $expiry = $_POST['expiry']
    $securitycode = $_POST['securitycode'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $address2 = $_POST['address2'];
    $address3 = $_POST['address3'];
    $town = $_POST['town'];
    ;}


    $query = "INSERT INTO card VALUES ('$card',$cardnumber, $expiry, $securitycode, '$name', '$address', '$address2', '$address3', '$twon' )"; /*query to insert the new values into the database*/




    if (!mysqli_query($con,$query))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('1 record added')</script>"; /*Displays a messgae to tell the user thatone record has been added to the database*/
    

    mysqli_close($con); 
}
?>
```

This is the error in php_error_log:

> [17-Mar-2015 15:34:52 Europe/Berlin] PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/paymentback.php on line 5
>
> [17-Mar-2015 15:35:47 Europe/Berlin] PHP Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myconnect.php on line 7
>
> [17-Mar-2015 15:39:56 Europe/Berlin] PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$card' (T_VARIABLE) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/paymentback.php on line 6
>
> [17-Mar-2015 19:38:42 Europe/Berlin] PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/paymentback.php on line 38

Comment: Well... What is your problem? Tell us...

Comment: when I add the information and hit submit nothing happens and nothing is added to the database

Comment: What do you mean? Are you seeing blank page? At the first sight, you need to include single quotes for ever variable you wanna insert in your `INSERT` statement. I'm sorry but its not clear for me what do you need...

Comment: Also, there is an extra semicolon in the first IF statement...

Comment: yes I see a blank page and nothing is added to the database

Comment: Good. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your file to see any possible error and show us. I'll post an answer where you need to fix then

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: this didn't help still getting a blank page

Comment: did you add this line at the top of you PHP file right after `<?php`? Its not possible since you have **Syntax** error

Comment: yes i did but still i get a blank page

Comment: see my answer. especially the 2nd point

Comment: now see the 3rd point. You have done another mistake

Answer (score 2):

Checking you HTML form, you need to include attribute `name` for your submit button:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

After submitting the button... You need to use `isset()` or `empty()` function for your `$_POST['submit']` like this:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $card = $_POST['card'];
    $cardnumber = $_POST['cardnumber'];
    $expiry = $_POST['expiry'];
    $securitycode = $_POST['securitycode'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $address = $_POST['Address1'];
    $address2 = $_POST['Address2'];
    $address3 = $_POST['Address3'];
    $town = $_POST['town'];

    // The rest of your code including SQL Statements

}
```

Check your attributes name in your form: `Address`, `Address2`, `Address3` has a capital **A**. Don't forget to include semicolon in each of $_POST attribution as well...

But make sure you include your entire script code inside this IF Statement since they only needs to execute if `$_POST` was *set*.

**NOTICE THERE IS AN EXTRA SEMICOLON INSIDE THIS IF STATEMENT, REMOVE IT AS WELL**

Also I notice you missed some single quotes inside your SQL Statement. But FIRST, I wanna warning you:

- "Consider using [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*."

  ```
  $query = "INSERT INTO card VALUES ('$card','$cardnumber', '$expiry', '$securitycode', '$name', '$address', '$address2', '$address3', '$twon' )";
  ```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: [17-Mar-2015 19:38:42 Europe/Berlin] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/paymentback.php on line 38

Comment: What is the content on **line 38**? I think you can analyze that. Probably there is an extra closing `}`. You need to check your code to see if there too many _curly braces_.

Comment: thats what it was but even with taking it out and having no errors the code still doesn't work

Comment: it now brings up an display box with 'missing information' even if I have filled in each text box and doesn't add anything to the database

Comment: this error message is now showing [17-Mar-2015 20:04:55 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: Address in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/paymentback.php on line 12

Comment: Its because you don't have field named with `Address` and you are calling  `$_POST['Address']`. Try to change to `$_POST['Address1']` and rum again. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Please. Don't say _still not working_. Always check your php_error_log  to see other errors and show me. You can try to solve yourself if  you know these possible error.

Comment: the problem is that its not coming up with any errors now but it still won't work

Answer (score 0):

You don't detect that the form was submitted. You need to add name to your submit button:

Change

```
<input type="submit">
```

to

```
<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

And because submit has no value here, change

```
if($_POST["submit"])
```

to

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
```

Otherwise your statement will be evaluated to false.

Also you have two select elements with the same name "expiry" - you must differentiate to get year and month.

BTW, use `mysqli_real_escape_string` to sanitize the input.

Comment: @Rebekah Try it now with changes from my edited answer

Comment: still not joy with it

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit">
```

The submit element needs a name.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have done 3 mistakes:

1. When you write

   ```
   if($_POST["submit"])
   ```

then, the word you write in the quotations means that it is a name of something. In this case, you are telling the PHP code that "submit" is a name of something but the problem is occurring because you have not given this name to anything.

By this PHP code, you want to target:

```
<input type="submit">
```

But this is wrong, since it does not have any name. So, you should write:

```
<input type="submit" name="Your Desired Name">
```

and then, your PHP code will become:

```
if($_POST["Your given name to input Button"])
```

2. The second mistake is what is that extra semicolon doing there at the end of if statement in PHP  code ??

   ```
   $town = $_POST['town'];;}
   ```
3. Missing a semicolon here as well

   `$expiry = $_POST['expiry']`

A suggestion:

In this PHP code

```
if (!mysqli_query($con,$query))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('1 record added')</script>"; /*Displays a messgae to tell the user thatone record has been added to the database*/
```

you should write else statement as well. It may not effect that much since if code goes into the if statement then, the die query will run, however, it's a good programming practice to use else statements.

Comment: i changed both of these and still get a blank page

Answer (score 0):

you have given the input name in capital and you are taking it in small in $_POST['']; correct every where in php or html and than try